# PostgreSQL 12 streaming replication active, password change not working

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL master and a standby. The streaming replication is configured and replicating. If I change the password on the master the streaming replication stops after a while. On the standby I can detect a file postgresql.auto.conf which contains the "primary_conninfo" but with the old password.

The standby was prepared by using pg_basebackup with -R option. It did 
automatically create the files standby.signal and postgresql.auto.conf .

Can I change the password for db users in a master standy configuration and if yes, what is the recommended way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`primary_conninfo` is specified in the recovery configuration. Configuration files are not changed by replication.

If you change the password of the user that the standby server uses to connect to the primary, you also have to edit `primary_conninfo` on the standby server, otherwise it won't be able to connect the nest time it is restarted (or loses the connection in some other way).

Comment: I edited the file with the new password but when using the command "select * from pg_stat_wal_receiver;" it does not show an entry. The replication seems not to run. Do I have to restart the postgres process after editing the file? Or maybe you can describe best practice steps how to make password changes on master and  standby.

Comment: Yes, after editing the recovery configuration, you have to restart the standby. I think I gave you the procedure: change the password on the primary (standby continues to run), then edit the recovery configuration.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, after editing postgresql.auto.conf and restarting the postgres process, the replication works again. Is it possible to initiate the password change on the standby without manually editing the file?

Comment: No, that is impossible.

Comment: Wow, your response time is incredible! Too bad that the file has to be edited without an API. Especially considering that there might be caracters to escape and/or you write scripts that update the configuration files.

Comment: From PostgreSQL v12 on, `primary_conninfo` is in the regular configuration, so you can change it with `ALTER SYSTEM` via SQL. You still need the restart. So consider upgrading to v12 if you want to avoid editing a configuration file.

Comment: I tried it with v12. I have the following statements in the config file:  
`primary_conninfo = 'user=myuser password=''mypass'' host=192.168.74.2 port=5432 sslmode=prefer sslcompression=0 gssencmode=disable krbsrvname=postgres target_session_attrs=any'
primary_slot_name = 'my_replication_slot'`  
If I use `ALTER SYSTEM SET primary_conninfo = 'password=''myChangedPass'''` it replaces the complete statement.  
Is it possible to only change the password?

Comment: You can get the current setting with the `current_setting` function, modify it however you want and set it with `ALTER SYSTEM`.

Comment: Ok, that will do the job. **pros:** prevents multiple file access of config file; **cons:** regex replacement; masking the password (i'm not shure if ' is a valid character); extra validation needed if password is correct